# modify a yml file via cat command

Tags: r, linux, yaml

My .yml file looks like this

```
prod:
  a.name: name
  a.password: xxxxxxx
dev:
  b.name: asasas
  b.password: cscsc
```

Can I convert it to this using the cat command or R programming language

```
prod:
  a.name: aaaaaa
  a.password: bbbbbbb
dev:
  b.name: asasas
  b.password: cscsc
```

Comment: There's a [yaml](https://cran.r-project.org/package=yaml) package on CRAN that allows you to read and write a YAML file. Have you tried using that yet?

Comment: sed would be a better tool than cat.